# Ruby: How can I process a CSV file with "bad commas"?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

I need to process a CSV file from FedEx.com containing shipping history. Unfortunately FedEx doesn't seem to actually test its CSV files as it doesn't quote strings that have commas in them.

For instance, a company name might be "Dog Widgets, Inc." but the CSV doesn't quote that string, so any CSV parser thinks that comma before "Inc." is the start of a new field.

Is there any way I can reliably parse those rows using Ruby?

The only differentiating characteristic that I can find is that the commas that are part of a string have a space after then. Commas that separate fields have no spaces. No clue how that helps me parse this, but it is something I noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's an idea: You could replace each instance of comma-followed-by-a-space with a unique character, then parse the CSV as usual, then go through the resulting rows and reverse the replace.

Answer (score 9):

you can use a negative lookahead

```
>> "foo,bar,baz,pop, blah,foobar".split(/,(?![ \t])/)
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "pop, blah", "foobar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along these lines..

using gsub to change the ', ' to something else

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "foo,bar,baz,pop, blah,foobar".gsub(/,\ /,'| ').split(',')
[
    [0] "foo",
    [1] "bar",
    [2] "baz",
    [3] "pop| blah",
    [4] "foobar"
]
```

and then remove the | after words.

Answer (score 0):

If you are so lucky as to only have one field like that, you can parse the leading fields off the start, the trailing fields off than end and assume whatever is left is the offending field. In python (no habla ruby) this would look something like:

```
fields = line.split(',') # doesn't work if some fields are quoted
fields = fields[:5] + [','.join(fields[5:-3])] + fields[-3:]
```

Whatever you do, you should be able at a minimum determine the number of offending commas and that should give you something (a sanity check if nothing else).