# Ruby: How can I edit the contents of a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, file, csv, editing

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963090/ruby-how-can-i-process-a-csv-file-with-bad-commas), how can I edit the contents of a CSV file?

I ultimately need to replace all instances of something and I need to do that before I open the file for parsing (with FasterCSV).

So, using Ruby I need to open, edit, and save the CSV file.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/CSV.html) module.

Comment: I don't understand how to use that to replaces all instances of something in the file...